# How do I increase the number of instances in EC2 Linux + networking ECS Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I created a cluster and have a service with tasks running on it. I want to increase the number of machines (EC2 instances) that the cluster has access to (basically giving my cluster more juice). I am using EC2 Linux + Networking (not Fargate). Is an auto scaling group the only way to do that? Or is there another way? I tried reading the docs (or maybe I found the wrong docs) but I cannot see an easy way to do that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are many ways. You are looking for an automated way or manual?

Comment: Thank you @Marcin , I wanted to do it manually

Answer (score 1):

When you create a cluster with EC2 + Linux you automatically get an auto scaling group. Look for the auto scaling group related to your cluster. Set the max and desired equal to your new value. That is it!